# How to manage library repository inside main project repository

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a main project repository on github that contains the code of my PHP/laravel project. To keep some parts of the project seperate, an extra repository was created which contains libraries.

These libraries are used by my main project. The file structure looks like this:

```
/main_folder/...<code linked to main project repository>
/main_folder/vendors/libraries/...<library code linked to libraries repository>
```

Note that the library code is located in a subfolder of the main project.

The project uses composer to manage the packages.
I am using Visual Studio Code for development.

Every time composer update is ran, the packages in /vendors/ are updated, including my libraries package. The problem with this set up, is that it makes it awkward to quickly test library code changes. I've found 2 ways to make this somewhat work, but neither seems like the correct way of doing things.

Option A)

- I clone my libraries repository into the vendors directory. Changes made locally to the libraries, are then immediately accessible in the main project.

The downside is that I need to remove my libraries repository every time I run composer update on my main project. Composer can't deal with the .git files in the directory.

Option B)

- I clone my libraries repository into a directory outside the main project. Composer then works great, and I can manage my libraries packages properly.

The downside is that I need to run composer update every time I make a change in the libraries which I want to test with my main code. The main project is used to debug and test the libraries. This takes a few minutes for every change, which makes debugging quite painful.

Questions:

1. Can option A or B be adjusted to work smoothly?
2. Is there another option that would make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your library dependency to be a [symlink to a local directory](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) (Path Repository). Using a symlink, you can still develop the library from its dev folder while working in the client application.

When your library development is done, you can then push it to your remote repository (or packagist, anything you need), tag a version and configure a proper dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [franzliedke/studio](https://github.com/franzliedke/studio), which will symlink your local packages into the vendor directory automatically.

It requires no modifications to your project `composer.json`, and can support multiple local packages via its `studio.json` config file.

Comment: Can't you achieve the same by configuring composer in the composer.json in $HOME/.config/composer for the path repositories? Requires no modification on the project level config as well and stabilizes the build when disabling plugins and scripts to prevent side-effects.